# control figure & table placement - specific case

Tags: floats, positioning

Attached an image of my document output.
Notice the last page (bottom-right) is almost empty and contains only a small table.
The document continues after this page for a few more pages of text.
I would like to have this table in the bottom of the second (top-right) page, and it seems to fit there pretty nicely (with paint...)
I've tried playing around with the placement options [!htbp], and moving the table to different locations in the .tex file but couldn't get it to work.
Any ideas how to accomplish this? (a minimal working example would not be so minimal in this case...)

[image]

Comment: FAQ references (and duplicates) include: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD).

Comment: the first link gave the answer: "There is no bottom area for page-wide floats in two-column mode"

Comment: Not sure whether [`dblfloatfix`](http://ctan.org/pkg/dblfloatfix) would be of help. Consider reading the UK TeX FAQ entry: [Placing two-column floats at bottom of page](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=2colfloat).

Comment: Actually, a bottom page-wide float really doesn't look that good. So I abandoned the idea. Thanks for your help, Werner.